# Which configuration files override /etc/default/locale?

Tags: configuration, startup, locale, defaults

For some strange reason, I find my I have several `LC_` locale variables set to a value I don't recognize having chosen (`en_ZA.UTF-8`). So, I want to set it differently - permanently, from the command-line, and using the appropriate configuration file(s).

But which files are these? I would think it should be `/etc/default/locale`, at least at the system level. But in there I see:

```
#  File generated by update-locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
```

Are there other files Where  `LC_MONETARY`, `LC_TIME`, etc. may be set? I grepped around and could find any suspects.

PS - I'm using Debian Stretch.

Comment: Any of the various shell startup files (`/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, etc...) as well as `/etc/environment` are good candidates for being the offender, but you might as well just try a wide search in all of `/etc` and your home directory if you're not in a hurry. There shouldn't be too many false matches for the string `en_ZA` :-) BTW, running stretch in 2016 is a bit of a stretch...

Comment: @Celada: Debian Stretch is the current Debian testing (Debian 9). Also, `grep -r en_ZA /etc` yielded _nothing_.

Comment: Uh, oops, I mixed it up with squeeze (which is getting pretty old, right?)! stretch, squeeze, squish, whatever, it's all deformations in toys :-)

Answer (score 2):

Locale settings are conveyed through environment variables, so they can be set in any of the many places where environment variables can be set. `/etc/default/locale` is where the system default locale is recorded if you go through the system locale configuration interface, but settings could be in any other place where environment variables are set, such as (I'm just listing the most common ones):

- `/etc/profile`
- `/etc/profile.d/*`
- `/etc/environment`
- `~/.profile`, or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.login` or `~/.zprofile` depending on your login shell
- `~/.pam_environment`
- (for shells running in a terminal only) `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/zshrc`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, etc.

Searching through the whole of `/etc` and your dot files should find it:

```
grep -rs en_ZA /etc ~/.[!.]*
```

Locale settings are set from `LANG` if unset, and `LC_ALL` trumps all. In the output of `locale`, settings are printed in double quotes if they're induced from `LANG` or `LC_ALL` as opposed to set explicitly.